# PDF of a function of a bounded linear random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, random

I'm sure I solved this correctly, but the bounds are a bit tricky.

There's an rv w/pdf
$$
f(y) = \frac{a+by}{c}
$$
bounded on $(1,3)$ and function $W=Y^2$, I need to compute $f(w)$.

I decided to take  a longer route, and start with CDF of $Y$, which comes out to
$$
F(y) = \frac{a}{c}(y-1) + \frac{b}{2c}(y^2 - 1)
$$
and, since $Y$ is bounded, and $W=Y^2, W$ is also bounded: $(1,9)$. Now, using the CDF approach,
$$
P(W<w)= P(Y^2<w) = P(-\sqrt{w}<Y<\sqrt{w}) = F_{Y}(\sqrt{w})-F_{Y}(-\sqrt{w})
$$
This is where my confusion started, becasue $-\sqrt{w}$ is certainly negative, and $F(y)$ is only defined for $y>1$. What should the  lower bound be then? I used $F(1)=0$ to get
$$
F_W(w) = \frac{a}{c}(\sqrt{w}-1) + \frac{b}{2c}(w-1), 1 <w<9 
$$
Differentiating wrt $w$, I get
$$
f_W(w) = \frac{a}{2c \sqrt{w}} + \frac{b}{2c}
$$
which should be the correct answer, but I'm still hesitant about that lower bound $F_{Y}(1)$. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but

$$f_Y(y)=\int_1^3\frac{a+by}{c}dy \ne 1$$

thus you have to normalize $f_Y$ first...

The problem is that I try to normalize it I get

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{a+by}{2(2b+a)}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(1;3)}(y)$$

thus $c$ disappears...

So check you $f_Y$ first...I  can assume that $a,b$ are density parameters while $c$ is a constant to be derived. In this case, using the following formula

$$f_W(w)=f_Y[g^{-1}(w)]\cdot|\frac{d}{dw}g^{-1}(w)|$$

You immediately get your desired density

$$f_W(w)=\frac{a+b\sqrt{w}}{4(2b+a)\sqrt{w}}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(1;9)}(w)$$

Comment: what if $a=2, b = 3, c = 16$? But in any case is my logic about the lower bound correct?

Comment: @Alex with these parameters, it works but 16 is derived as I showed in function of a and b; $c=2(2\times3+2)=16$. I added the complete solution for your density

Comment: @Alex Yes, your calculations are correct.